# pipe the package version number and create a git tag from the version number

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a git tag from the version number of a package.json file

```
PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version") | git tag -a ${PACKAGE_VERSION} -m “Version ${PACKAGE_VERSION}”
git push --tags
```

I am getting the version from the package.json file but the right hand side of the pipe is wrong

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe will start a sub-shell, that is, there, the `PACKAGE_VERSION` is not defined.

If you want to build the script as a 1-liner, you may replace the `|` with `&&`

See these examples:

```
kent$  x='foo'|echo $x
     <--- here the echo cmd prints nothing
kent$  x='foo' && echo $x
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a pipe? Just set your variable, and then use it in a separate statement.  (I haven't checked your command for setting the variable, but you say that it is working.)

```
PACKAGE_VERSION=..........

git tag -a ${PACKAGE_VERSION} -m "Version ${PACKAGE_VERSION}"
```